# make a input field required if radio is checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, onchange, required

Can I somehow insert the required attribute into an input field only if a certain radio is checked?

I have an input field named "ladder-meters" that is not required to be filled per default. But if the user checks a radio button that is named "ladder" the "ladder-meters" field are required to be filled.

My input looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ladder-meters" id="ladder-meters">
```

and should like this at the onchange event on the radio

```
<input type="text" name="ladder-meters" id="ladder-meters" required>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy to achieve with jQuery:

```
$('#ladder').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked') {
        $('#ladder-meters').attr('required');
    } else {
        $('#ladder-meters').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: Used this! Works as intended :) Thanks!

Comment: Seven convoluted lines of jQuery will always beat 3 lines of plain ol' javascript.
Note to self: must included more libraries.

Comment: @ColBeseder - 3 lines of plain JavaScript that won't work in old versions of IE. It will increase in line count as you add in feature detects for `addEventListener` and then add the `attachEvent` version. Having said that, there is no mention of jQuery in the question, so there shouldn't really have been any jQuery answers.

Comment: why do i got `Uncaught TypeError: mycheckbox.is is not a function`?

Comment: a bracket is missing in this code on line 2.
after (':checked') add ) bracket

Comment: The code is missing a parenthesis: `if($(this).is(":checked")) {`

Answer (score 18):

```
document.getElementById("ladder").addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.getElementById("ladder-meters").required = this.checked ;
})
```

Whenever the checkbox is clicked, the required attribute will be changed to match the checked attribute of the checkbox. To reverse this relationship, replace `this.checked` with `!this.checked`

This may need some adjustment to suit your specific project.

This will work with this checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='ladder' name='ladder' />
```

Answer (score 18):

Tried F. Orvalho, didn't work for me, I had to use

```
$('#ladder').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#ladder-meters').prop('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#ladder-meters').prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

It could be usefull. Thx to F. Orvalho for the structure