# Form with JavaScript conditional validation

Tags: javascript, validation, conditional-statements

```js
$('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.':
      $('.field.SSN_No').hide();
      $('.field.SSN').show();
      break;

    case 'Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.':
      $('.field.SSN').hide();
      $('.field.SSN_No').show();
      break;
  }
});

function validateSSN() {
  if (!validateRequiredTextField('SSN', 'Social Security Number'))
    return false;

  var value = $('.field.SSN input').val();

  if (!isInteger(value) ||
    (value.length != 9) ||
    (value == '000000000') ||
    (value == '111111111') ||
    (value == '222222222') ||
    (value == '333333333') ||
    (value == '444444444') ||
    (value == '555555555') ||
    (value == '666666666') ||
    (value == '777777777') ||
    (value == '888888888') ||
    (value == '999999999') ||
    (value == '123456789')) {
    $('.field.SSN input').focus();
    alert("Invalid: Social Security Number");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validateForm() {
  if (!validateSSN())
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

```css
<style>fieldset {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 10px 12px 12px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.radio label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.field .radio label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.radio label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 28px;
}

.field label,
.EditingFormLabel {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.radio label,
.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

element.style {
  display: block;
}

.field {
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <h4>Personal:</h4>
    <div class="field SocialSecurity">
      <span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_lb" class="EditingFormLabel">Do you have a Social Security Number?</span>
      <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpsocialsecurity" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">

        <span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list" class="radio radio-list-vertical">
    <input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number." />
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0">As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.</label><br />
    
    <input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number." />
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1">Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.</label></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field SSN" style="display: none;">
      <label id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_lb" class="EditingFormLabel" for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText">Social Security Number</label>

      <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpssn" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">

        <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SSN$txtText" type="text" maxlength="9" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

</html>
```

I have a web form with JavaScript.  My form has 2 radio buttons.  If the user chooses the first radio button, I need an additional field to show and to be required.  If the user chooses the second radio button, then the above field needs to be hidden and not be required.  Secondly, I need the said field, when required to be validated.

Do you have a Social Security Number?  (This field is called SocialSecurity)
(radio button 1) As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.
(radio button 2) Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.

If radio button 1 is chosen, then another field called SSN is shown and must be required, but ONLY if the user chooses radio button 1.   My current code is doing the show/hide properly, but is requiring the SSN even when the user picks choice 2.  I need it to ONLY be required and validate IF the user chooses radio button 1.

Here is my JS:

```
$('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function()
{
  if($(this).val() == 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.')
  {
    $('fieldset.SSN').show();
    $('.field.SSN input').focus();
  }
  else
    $('fieldset.SSN').hide();     
});

$('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function()
{
  switch($(this).val())
  {
    case 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.':
        $('.field.SSN_No').hide();
        $('.field.SSN').show();
      break;

    case 'Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.':
        $('.field.SSN').hide();
        $('.field.SSN_No').show();
       break;
  }     
});

function validateSSN()
{
  if (!validateRequiredTextField('SSN', 'Social Security Number'))
    return false;

  var value = $('.field.SSN input').val();

  if ( !isInteger(value)
    || (value.length != 9) 
    || (value == '000000000')
    || (value == '111111111')
    || (value == '222222222')
    || (value == '333333333')
    || (value == '444444444')
    || (value == '555555555')
    || (value == '666666666')
    || (value == '777777777')
    || (value == '888888888')
    || (value == '999999999')
    || (value == '123456789'))
  {
    $('.field.SSN input').focus();
    alert("Invalid: Social Security Number");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validateForm()
{
  if (!validateSSN())
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="field SocialSecurity">
<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_lb" class="EditingFormLabel">Do you have a Social Security Number?</span> 
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpsocialsecurity" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">

<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list" class="radio radio-list-vertical">
          <input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number." />
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0">As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.</label><br />

          <input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number." />
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1">Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.</label></span>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="field SSN" style="display: none;">
    <label id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_lb" class="EditingFormLabel" for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText">Social Security Number</label> 

      <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpssn" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">

            <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SSN$txtText" type="text" maxlength="9" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText" class="form-control" />
      </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could you incorporate your HTML and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without it it is very hard to debug your code.

Comment: I tried to extract the section of the form that applies to this area.

Comment: Right now, nothing in the code here calls `validateForm`, so the question is incomplete. You can easily make a field required or not by adding or removing the `required` attribute on the field itself. Then, in `validateForm`, just check if the field's `required` attribute is present and only call `validateSSN()` if it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make a input field required if radio is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967519/make-a-input-field-required-if-radio-is-checked)

Comment: But what if I want it to only be required IF the user picks radio choice 1?  The SSN field is only visible if they do.  Otherwise, it is hidden.

Comment: How do you make the requirement conditional?